# Median If Equation on Excel file

Tags: excel, if-statement, median

I was trying to use Median with an If to find the median of a column for values greater than 0. 
This seems to be what I have seen others use; however, this formula does not seem to be correctly working for me.
Does anyone seem to see the problem?
Thank you!

```html
=MEDIAN(IF(X3:X92 > 0,X3:X92))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula

```
=MEDIAN(IF($X3:$X92<>0,$X3:$X92))
```

**AND also use Shift+Ctrl+Enter when you enter!**

That is important, and probably what you forgot.